# How to order firebase query by boolean

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a boolean field in my firestore documents. I want to order the collection by the boolean. Document with `answer` boolean true should appear before documents with `answer` boolean false.

```
   const item: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> =
       this.afs.collection(`items`,
          (ref) => ref.where('questionId', '==', questionId)
                      .orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc')
                      .orderBy('answer'));
   return item.valueChanges();
```

items in firestore are in the following order

```
items = {[
 {
id: 1,
questionId: x1,
answer: false,
updatedAt: 848939
},
{
id: 2,
questionId: x2,
answer: false,
updatedAt: 848936
},
{
id: 3,
questionId: x3,
answer: true,
updatedAt: 848938
}
]}
```

When the query is done, I want the number three item to be at index 0...first item in results. Now I am getting only orderedBy updatedAt.

The above query doesn't give me the above-required result.
How do I conduct such a query?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure that the second ordering isn't changing the results of the first one?  Please edit the question to show both your source data, and how you expect the ordering to be in the query results.

Comment: @DougStevenson . I edited the question. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

As the documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) says:

> Data Type: Boolean
>
> Sort order: false < true

If you want documents with `true` to come first, you'll have to sort in descending order:

```
 .orderBy('answer', 'desc'));
```

Comment: I think of them as numbers (`true` as `1` and `false` as `0`) to remember this; if you want to sort higher numbers first (`true`) you need `desc`, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Change the direction of the sort for the answer field:

```
orderBy('answer', 'desc')
```